# Error while working with getLooper() method in android

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, android-looper

I am learning threading and concurrency in Android. I have created a basic program where the main thread sends an interrupt to the worker thread to stop the worker thread's processing. The main thread sends the interrupt after 5 seconds. I have 2 threads: a main thread and a worker thread.

Code:

```
package com.example.testthread;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a new thread and start it
        NewThread newThread = new NewThread();
        newThread.start();

        // Get the Looper of the new thread and create a Handler associated with it
        Looper looper = newThread.getLooper();

        mHandler = new Handler(looper);

        // Post a Runnable to the new thread's Handler after a delay of 5 seconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                newThread.interrupt();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    private static class NewThread extends Thread {

        private boolean isRunning = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            while (isRunning) {
                Log.d("NewThread", "Thread is running");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("NewThread", "Thread was interrupted");
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }

    }
}
```

Here, the getLooper() method is giving me error

[image]

Unable to solve the issue. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: your `NewThread` doesn't have `getLooper()` method, also `Thread` itself

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why you want to use a looper in a thread? There is a [HandlerThread](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java) class that does everything for you to prepare a looper. Do you mind using it?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to learn how to work with a looper without using a HandlerThread class. My above code matches the code present in a lot of documentation. Could you please provide me with a solution on how to work with looper without using HandlerThread? Will help me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

your `NewThread` doesn't have `getLooper()` method, also `Thread` itself. if you really need outer access to that looper you can look at source of [`HandlerThread`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java) and copy its realisation of stored-locally-`Looper`-`mLooper` for getting `getLooper()` method also in your `NewThread`

```
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper(); // obtain ref between prepare() and loop()
        notifyAll();
    }
    Looper.loop();
```

or just use `HandlerThread` strictly...